Why doesn't the light yellow background of my JavaFX application appear?
I want to display both a lightyellow background and text content on the screen. In this way, it is possible to cover 2D content on 3D scenes at the same time. Similar to the 2D content in CSGO games, such as crosshairs, health bars, and equipment bars. But the main scene of the program is 3D.
This is my code:
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Create the 2D content
            AnchorPane globalRoot = new AnchorPane();
         Color color = Color.LIGHTYELLOW;

         // Create the main Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(globalRoot, 1024, 768, color);
            Label label = new Label("this is AnchorPane example");
            globalRoot.getChildren().add(label);

                 // Configure and show the primary stage
                 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX 2D and 3D Integration");
                 primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Why the line "Color color = Color.LIGHTYELLOW;" not work?
enter image description here
When I comment out these two lines of code, lightyellow happens:
//Label label = new Label("this is AnchorPane example");
//globalRoot.getChildren().add(label);
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Create the 2D content
            AnchorPane globalRoot = new AnchorPane();
         Color color = Color.LIGHTYELLOW;

         // Create the main Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(globalRoot, 1024, 768, color);
            //Label label = new Label("this is AnchorPane example");
            //globalRoot.getChildren().add(label);

                 // Configure and show the primary stage
                 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX 2D and 3D Integration");
                 primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

enter image description here
But if I just comment the line, application not work well:
//globalRoot.getChildren().add(label);
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    // Create the 2D content
            AnchorPane globalRoot = new AnchorPane();
         Color color = Color.LIGHTYELLOW;

         // Create the main Scene
            Scene scene = new Scene(globalRoot, 1024, 768, color);
            Label label = new Label("this is AnchorPane example");
            //globalRoot.getChildren().add(label);

                 // Configure and show the primary stage
                 primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX 2D and 3D Integration");
                 primaryStage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

enter image description here

For a heads up display, assuming that is your goal, you should probably be using a subscene to layer a 2D scene with a transparent background on a 3D scene.

You’re seeing the background color of the anchor pane, which is applied by the default CSS stylesheet, which is loaded the first time you create a control. You can fix it with, e.g. globalRoot.setBackground(Background.fill(Color.TRANSPARENT)). This question is a duplicate, but I can’t find the original right now.

The linked duplicate does more than what you are asking, but I think it also provides info on the point the James_D made in comments.

Thank you, the answer of James_D is right, you have helped me so much.
